# Implementing a function that exhibits linearity

Tags: function-construction, syntax, core-language

I am trying to define a function $\mathbb{E}_t$ such that $\mathbb{E}_{t}[f[x_{s}]] = f[x_{s}]$ if s<=t, and $\mathbb{E}_{t}[f[x_{s}]] =  \mathbb{E}_{t}[f[x_{s}]]$ if s>t. $\mathbb{E}_{t}$ is linear such that $\mathbb{E}_{t}[x_{s}+y_{r}]=\mathbb{E}_{t}[x_{s}]+\mathbb{E}_{t}[y_{r}]$ and $\mathbb{E}_{t}[x_{s}*y_{r}]=\mathbb{E}_{t}[x_{s}]*\mathbb{E}_{t}[y_{r}]$

I tried (f:->x in this definition)

$\mathbb{E}_{t\_}[x_{s\_}] := If[Refine[t>s,Elment[\{t,s\},Reals]],x_{s},HoldForm[\mathbb{E}_{t}[x_{s}] ]]$
and
$\mathbb{E}_{t\_}[x\_+y\_]:=\mathbb{E}_{t}[x]+\mathbb{E}_{t}[y]$ 
and
$\mathbb{E}_{t}[x\_*y\_]:=\mathbb{E}_{t}[x]*\mathbb{E}_{t}[y]$

It works for the simple cases. However, it gives

$\mathbb{E}_{t}[x_{t}^{2}]=\mathbb{E}_{t}[x_{t}^{2}]$

instead of

$\mathbb{E}_{t}[x_{t}^{2}]=x_{t}^{2}$.

I suspect the reason is because the head of x*y is not the same as x^2. Is there an easier way to define such a function? I hope $\mathbb{E}_{t}$ will work for a more general function f. I used HoldForm so that I do not get an infinite loop.

Comment: Could you please reformat your code in a form that is copy and pastable (e.g. using the { } tool).

Comment: Subscript[\[DoubleStruckCapitalE], s_][Subscript[x_, t_]] := 
 If[Refine[s < t, Element[{t, s}, Reals]], 
  HoldForm[Subscript[\[DoubleStruckCapitalE], s][Subscript[x, t]]], 
  Subscript[x, t]];

Subscript[\[DoubleStruckCapitalE], s_][x_ + y_] := 
 Subscript[\[DoubleStruckCapitalE], s][x] + 
  Subscript[\[DoubleStruckCapitalE], s][y];
Subscript[\[DoubleStruckCapitalE], s_][x_*y_] := 
 Subscript[\[DoubleStruckCapitalE], s][x]*
  Subscript[\[DoubleStruckCapitalE], s][y]

Comment: Your rule is too ambiguous to work for any `f`, consider a definition with additional arguments, $\mathbb{E}_{t\_}[expr\_,x\_,s\_]$ for example.